Function defined by expression equivalent to rearrangements of that expression?
If I define a function $g(x) = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}$ then is this the same function as $f(x) = x$?
I’m not sure whether 0 is in the domain of g or not (obviously both functions tend to the same limit as x->0).

$g$ is not defined at $x=0$ (as  $1/0$ doesn't make sense), but $f$ is. So, they are not equal (assuming you take domain of $f$ to be $\Bbb R$).
Hope this helps. :)
